# Save portrait orientation into file in Nikon D5100

Tags: nikon-d5100

I had my first experience with my new Nikon D5100 yesterday, and I got surprised that the photos I took turning the camera 90 degres were not turned in the files when I copy then to my computer.

Does it need any special configuration in order to save the portrait orientation into the files? I was shooting in JPEG.

Answer (score 3):

```
   Setup Menu (Wrench) -> Auto Image Rotation

   Playback Menu (Triangle) -> Rotate Tall
```

Set the first above to on for image to appear rotated on the computer. Set the second for images to appear rotated on the camera.

*PS: It would probably have taken you less time if you searched for 'rotation' in the manual. I do recommend you read anyway, you'll discover many great things!*